# Convert from string to data in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-behind, typedescriptor

Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
Path path = new Path( ); 

string sData = "M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60 Z";

var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof( Geometry ) );
path.Data = ( Geometry )converter.ConvertFrom( sData );
```

but it won't compile, silverlight does not appear to have a TypeDescriptor class...

Comment: Have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047(v=VS.95).aspx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  Path path = XamlReader.Load("<Path Data=\"M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60\" />") as Path;
```

**Edit**

Should have been:

```
  public static GeneratePath(string data)
  {
      string pathEnvelope = "<Path xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" Data=\"{0}\"/>")
      return XamlReader.Load(String.Format(pathEnvelope, data)) as Path;
  }
```

Usage:-

```
  string data = "M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60";

  Path path = GeneratePath(data);
```

See follow up question: [xaml parse exception when attempting to load xaml from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935078/xaml-parse-exception-when-attempting-to-load-xaml-from-codebehind)