# xaml parse exception when attempting to load xaml from codebehind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have the following line of code defined in codebehind in silverlight:

```
Path path = XamlReader.Load( "<Path Data=\"F1 M 44.207,34.0669C 44.4841,33.7278 44.7612,33.3886 45.0383,33.0494\" />" ) as Path;
```

[image]

No idea why it's happening...

Comment: Sorry my bad, I should've remembered that in my answer to your previous answer.  Still Adam did rather well out of it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the exception states, you are missing the default namespace in your XAML document. The `<Path>` element needs an XML namespace.

Add the attribute `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` to your Path element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx

And for reference, in case you're not familiar with them, as XAML is just XML, here is an introduction to XML namespaces:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp